# Firefox and localhost development (cant be access localhost)

Tags: php, firefox, localhost

Im work on localhost, and all is good in all browser, exception Firefox, Firefox when i set `http://localhost` or localhost:80 or any thing its redirect me to ask search,

Im try to change default search engine and stop keyword.enable from about:config ..but still not work .

any suggestion for this problem,

thank a lot,

Comment: have you tried using `http://127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: Im try it, thats work mate, 

thank you ... set your answer thanks alot ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `http://localhost` does not work you can use `http://127.0.0.1/` which is the loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you need to clean the cache in Firefox. Go to Options - Advanced and clean the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing your http.conf file. Use a text editor to open "http.conf", search for "80" and change it to 8080. After that, enter "localhost:8080" in the URL box and see if it opens.